# Which noise dampening washers (silicone, neoprene, rubber, etc…) fit the screws in a PC case?

Tags: hard-drive, case, case-mods, noise-cancelling

I'm building a case to be extra quiet and would like to add washers to the case and drive screws. As I understand it, washers made of silicone, neoprene, rubber, etc. can assist with vibrations and dampen case noise slightly.

There are a few types of screws in a case. To find washers for them my question is: what sized washers go with what sized screws, or what is the name for these washers?

Comment: The best washers like this fit into the hole (squeeze fit) and allow the screw to go through. Smaller screw or larger hole usually needed. Look through an electronics part catalogue for this.

Answer (score 1):

They will almost certainly all be M3. Any 'standard' PC screw and washer sets will contain M3 screws, stand-offs and washers. You'll also find M5 chassis fan screws.

[image]

Some cases come with drive bays that include rubber sleeves for the hard drive screws. These are called hard drive screw damping rings. My Fractal define R4 has these.

A lot of quality case fans also come with rubber grommets in the corners, where they're mounted. Examples include those from Be quiet! which I use.

Comment: What sized washers go with M3 screws?

Comment: M3, as per the image above

Comment: So the size of M3 is 3 millimeters, is that correct? A 3mm washer will work with an M3 screw?

Comment: Correct, 3mm ID (internal diameter) washer.